# Ionic v4 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework

```html
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SelecttopicPage } from '../selecttopic/selecttopic.page';
import { ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';
import { Media } from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

const MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediaFiles';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploadvid',
  templateUrl: './uploadvid.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploadvid.page.scss'],
})
export class UploadvidPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myvideo') myVideo: any;
  //uploadVid: FormGroup;
  public filePath: string;
  public mediaFiles = [];
  public isAndroid: boolean;

  uploadVid = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    topic: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    target: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  PERMISSION = {
    WRITE_EXTERNAL: this.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    READ_EXTERNAL: this.diagnostic.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    CAMERA: this.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA,
  };

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    public modalCtrl: ModalController, 
    public platform: Platform, 
    public actionSheetController: ActionSheetController, 
    public storage: Storage, 
    public mediaCapture: MediaCapture, 
    public media: Media, 
    public file: File, 
    private diagnostic: Diagnostic, 
    private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { 

    // this.uploadVid = formBuilder.group({
    //   title: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    //   topic: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    //   target: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    // });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkIfMobile();
  }

  loadStoredVideo(){
    this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
        this.mediaFiles = JSON.parse(res) || [];
    });
  }

  checkIfMobile(){
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      this.isAndroid = true;
    }else{
      this.isAndroid = false;
    }
  }

  async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: SelecttopicPage,
      //componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss((topic) => {

      console.log("topic2: "+topic);
      this.uploadVid.controls['topic'].setValue(topic);

    })

    return await modal.present();

  }

  // for web & ios
  handleFileSelect(evt){
    this.filePath = evt.target.files;
    alert("Selected Video: "+this.filePath);
  }

  // for android
  async openVidOption() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: "Albums",
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Camera',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'camera',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Delete clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Gallery',
        role: 'cancel',
        icon: 'folder-open',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

  checkAndroidPerm(){
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
       //this.requestAllPermissions();
       this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
        (success) => {console.log('Succes granted the permissions');
        this.captureVideo()},
        (err) => {this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)}
    );

    this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]);
    }
  }

  // requestAllPermissions(){
  //   const permissions = Object.keys(this.PERMISSION).map(k => this.PERMISSION[k]);
  //   this.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermissions(permissions).then((status) => {
  //           alert(JSON.stringify(status));
  //       }, error => {
  //           alert('Error: '+ error);
  //   });
  // }

  captureVideo(){
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
      limit: 1,
      duration: 30
    }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res: MediaFile[]) => {
        //this.storeMediaFiles(res);
        let capturedFile = res[0];
        console.log('capturedFile: '+capturedFile);
        let fileName = capturedFile.name;
        let dir = capturedFile['localURL'].split('/');
        dir.pop();
        let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');
        let toDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;

        this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory, fileName, toDirectory, fileName).then(res => {
          let url = res.nativeURL.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
          this.storeMediaFiles([{name: fileName, size: capturedFile.size, localURL: url}]);
        });
    });
  }

  storeMediaFiles(files){
    this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res =>{
      if(res){
        let arr = JSON.parse(res);
        arr = arr.concat(files);
        this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr));
      }else{
        this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(files));
      }
      this.mediaFiles = this.mediaFiles.concat();
    })
  }

  playFile(myFile){
    console.log('play: ', myFile);
    let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
    video.src = myFile.localURl;
  }



  

}
```

I am new in Ionic and was working on video capture functionality from this [tutorial](https://ionicacademy.com/capture-audio-video-local/). When I build android apk and opened the app I got blank screen. So I checked in computer browser and got error as shown in screenshot. I tried to search for its solution and found this posts [Link1](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2621) and [Link2](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/502) but this also did not resolved my issue.

If anyone can help me in this regard, it would be good. Thanks in advance.

```css
// config.xml

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filechooser" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepicker" spec="^1.1.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="^5.0.2">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.8" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^3.0.2" />
```

```html
// package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.9",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^1.0.2",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "1.0.0",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "1.0.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "angular-progress-http": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepicker": "^1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.9",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.7.0-rc.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.7.0-rc.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.7.0-rc.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.7.0-rc.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Might be an issue with the way you are accessing the media capture plugin. can you please paste the component code.

Comment: It's dying on the line:

  __decorate([
        Cordova({
            successIndex: 1,
            errorIndex: 2
        })

I'm completely new to Ionic / Cordova, but this happened to me after I installed the GooglePlus plugin. Seems to me like Ionic v4 might not be ready for use and I'll likely go to Ionic 3 and see if that works for me.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All I had to do was:
In dependencies, instead of `"@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.12.0"` I wrote `"@ionic-native/media-capture": "^5.0.0-beta.14"`. After that I typed `npm update` in CLI. And in my page component I used `import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';`. The important part here is `/ngx` as described in this [link](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module). Well I had to do this for AndroidPermissions, Diagnostic, Media and File. After that issue was solved. Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

solved by installing

npm install --save @ionic-native/media-capture@4.20.0

Answer (score 1):

guys, I am building a project with ionic 4 + angular 7, I'm trying to use ionic file system on my project,
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

following this page, after installing all dependencies when I try to import "File" into my "appModule.ts" I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at vendor.js:85920 at 
Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/native_plugin/index.js
// native_plugin = any native component

fix the issues, with:
`npm i -s @ionic-native/xxx@5.0.0-beta.14`

- Use Angular 6 and 6+ version

`import { xxx } from '@ionic-native/xxx/ngx`
`import { file } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';`

- without using Angular

`import { xxx } from '@ionic-native/xxx';
import { file } from '@ionic-native/file';`

Lastly check the @ionic-native/xxx versions on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/xxx
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/file

you have to use the version 5.x.x for ANGULAR and 4.x.x ANGULAR-IONIC.
Check your project type on your ionic.config.json file

Answer (score 0):

If use you Ionic v4, use should strictly only use ionic native v5 beta. In your package.json I see that one signal is on v4.12.2 which is not correct, you should upgrade it to v5.0.0-beta.15